# How to bulk update youtube videos description

Tags: youtube-api

We just changed the structure of our website and now we have to update the description of all our YouTube videos (around 750 video); in the description there should be a link to our website to buy the pdf file of the musical sheet shown on the video, and the new link structure is "example.com/?v={the yt video id}" (ex: example.com/?v=EIghgjBddo)

the new description template should be like this

```
Buy the pdf file: example.com/?v=EIghgjBddo
Facebook: fb.com/xxx
Pinterest: pinterest.com/xxx
don't forget to subscribe and like...
...
```

Is there a way to automatically bulk generate all the descriptions at once using some google API, because it is almost impossible to be done manually. the website is working with php and and jquery if that could help

Comment: Have you checked the documentation what does it say?

Comment: No, there's no bulk video update feature that YouTube Data API offers. You need to iterate over all your videos for to update each one of them separately (programmatically).